# how to read yaml in multiple row using python

Tags: python, yaml

we are reading the yaml file with below code in python but its giving me [1 rows x 30 columns]
but i want it in 2 rows. 1 row for my_table_01 and another for my_table_02(giving sample data below the code)

```
import pandas as pd
from yaml import safe_load
def read_yaml(path):
    #fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        df = pd.json_normalize(safe_load(f))
    return df
df_master = read_yaml('new 7.yml')
print(df_master)
```

my new 7.yml having below data,

```
cat new 7.yml-->
config_queries: 
            my_table_01 :
                           PIPELINE_NAME: "table_01"
                           RUN_FLAG: "True"  
                           STAGE: "edw_to_eim"
                           SUBJECT_AREA: "account"
                           SOURCE_DATABASE: "dev_db"
                           SOURCE_TABLE_NAME: "table"
                           TARGET_DATABASE: "dev_db"
                           TARGET_TABLE_NAME: "table"
                           TARGET_TABLE_TYPE: "ed"
                           DELTA_COLUMN: "N"
                           DELTA_COLUMN_NAME: "N"
                           DOP_VALUE: "N"
                           SOURCE_QUERY_KPI: {'tab_kpi_01':True,'tab_kpi_02':True}
                           TARGET_QUERY_KPI: {'tab_kpi_01':True,'tab_kpi_02':True}
                                                                                                                         
            my_table_02  : 
                           PIPELINE_NAME: "table_02"
                           RUN_FLAG: "True"  
                           STAGE: "edw_to_eim"
                           SUBJECT_AREA: "account"
                           SOURCE_DATABASE: "dev_db"
                           SOURCE_TABLE_NAME: "table"
                           TARGET_DATABASE: "dev_db"
                           TARGET_TABLE_NAME: "table"
                           TARGET_TABLE_TYPE: "ed"
                           DELTA_COLUMN: "N"
                           DELTA_COLUMN_NAME: "N"
                           DOP_VALUE: "N"
                           SOURCE_QUERY_KPI: {'tab_kpi_01':True}
                           TARGET_QUERY_KPI: {'tab_kpi_01':True}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_normalize` expects a `list` of `dicts`, not a single nested `dict` if it is to create multiple rows. You therefore need to 'unpack' your nested `dict` into a `list` of `dicts`, for example by taking the `values()` of `config_queries`:

```
import pandas as pd        
from yaml import safe_load
def read_yaml(path):
    #fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        df = pd.json_normalize([safe_load(f)['config_queries'].values()])
    return df
df_master = read_yaml('new 7.yml')
print(df_master)

#   PIPELINE_NAME RUN_FLAG  ... TARGET_QUERY_KPI.tab_kpi_01 TARGET_QUERY_KPI.tab_kpi_02
0      table_01     True  ...                        True                        True
1      table_02     True  ...                        True                         NaN

[2 rows x 16 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for this and is there any way to read only particular key .i.e. here i just want to read my_table_02

Comment: yes, just use `safe_load(f)['config_queries']['my_table_02']`